# How to create a child class of numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I would like to create a class which inherits the magic methods of a numpy.ndarray, yet be able to add my own attributes to it.

To do so, I have tried:

```
import numpy as np

class tryclass(np.ndarray):
    def __init__(self, array, name):
        super().__new__(array)
        self.name = name

array = np.array([1,2,3,4])
tryins = tryclass(array, 'try')
```

But I go this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classtest1.py", line 11, in <module>
    tryins = tryclass(array=array, name='try')
TypeError: ndarray() missing required argument 'shape' (pos 1)
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `tryclass(np.array ...` should be `tryclass(array ...`, right?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it was indeed the cause for the error in my code, I updated the code and got the above error instead.

Comment: I suggest you review this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.subclassing.html